# mysql installation ubuntu

Tags: mysql

i tried to install mysql with this command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

but it dosen't work

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Aucune version du paquet mysql-server-5.5 n'est disponible, mais il existe dans la base
de données. Cela signifie en général que le paquet est manquant, qu'il est devenu obsolète
ou qu'il n'est disponible que sur une autre source
Cependant les paquets suivants le remplacent :
  mysql-common:i386 mysql-server-5.7:i386 mysql-server-5.7 mysql-common
  mysql-testsuite-5.7:i386 mariadb-server-10.1:i386 mysql-testsuite-5.7
  mariadb-server-10.1 mysql-server-core-5.7:i386 mysql-server-core-5.7
  percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7:i386 percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7

E: Le paquet « mysql-server-5.5 » n'a pas de version susceptible d'être installée
```

is-there a solution ?

Comment: What do you get if you try to install the package `mysql-server` (not `mysql-server-5.5`)?

Comment: Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 mysql-server : Dépend: mysql-server-5.7 mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».

Comment: please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1166865/edit) your error output to including English Language into this International Community. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What operating system do you have?

Mysql 5.5 is not officially available in Ubuntu 16.04.

This page shows how it is installed but I do not recommend installing it as a current version or at least version 5.6 is better.

https://gist.github.com/ahmadhasankhan/48fc9fc9a19807daef1622751a56884b